# How to connect PHP web service on BlueMix and Android app?

Tags: php, android, json, db2, ibm-cloud

I need to create a connection between a SQL DB2 database located on BlueMix and an Android App.

To do so, I wanted to create a web service to handle the communication between the database and the app using JSON data.

This web service is written in PHP, which needs to be "associated" to the SQL DB2 database located on BlueMix.

Is there a way I can do this in Bluemix?
Thanks.

Comment: just a comment...you might find it easier to use ClearDB MySQL with PHP instead of DB2

Comment: I know,I would have liked to use Clear DB MySQL but the project I am working on requests a Ibm Db2 database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. In the Bluemix console, click on your application, bind existing service and then select the sqldb service. It will then prompt you to restage. After the restage, you can read the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable in your php code to get the database credentials.

[This thread](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/20036/how-to-compile-php-with-db2-support-in-bluemix.html) has detailed steps